# Windows 7- Data Recovery done, laptop hard drive is not working

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, 64-bit, operating-systems, hard-drive-recovery

I have a HP Laptop running Windows 7 - 64 bit that got infected with Virus in June. I was unable to perform a recovery of that system and as the laptop was purchased from US I needed to order the Recovery Drive from there. As it took time for me to receive the Recovery Drive from US e I installed the Windows to get the Laptop in working condition till than. Now I have received the Recovery Drives but I am unable to install it as system is giving the error message and not letting me install the Operating System. 'Data Recovery' has been done system is now formatted the only error I am getting is while uploading Operating System and software.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What are the exact errors, when do they appear and what are the results of your tries?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, sometimes systems glitch in just such a way that doing a system restore mysteriously fails. Wipe the hard drive with [dban](http://www.dban.org/) - a basic zeroing will do, and try doing the restore after that.